# Abrruptly CPU usage goes to 99% in ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 in aws. after every few hours I see the CPU usage goes to 99%. I am unable to find the process causing this issue.

Is there any flag which i can set to see the culprit process when I restart the ec2 instance?
I am running ubuntu 20 in the EC2 and the instance type is t2 micro.
Below are processes that I am running

1. Mysql
2. Mongo
3. A spring boot service

I think if these process is causing the issue then it should happen after few minutes of when I start these services but it is happening in absurd way after few hours

Comment: With this information it may be just a wild guess. You need to do proper profiling. My guess - a micro instance with a spring, mongodb and mysql is like cramping 3 bodybuilders into a Fiat 500 backseat. High CPU may be a JVM GC gasping for more memory

Comment: but the stats shows that CPU usage goes high not the memory

Comment: When java has not enough memory, then gc is very busy to get som free space, so it may or may not be the reason. As I said, you should profile the apps or get better insight. Otherwise it's all just guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `top` program to see what's consuming the most CPU.

This program is normally used from a terminal window, as it refreshes the display every few seconds (by default, 10, but you can change this). If you consistently see this performance issue, then simply log in, run `top`, and look at what it says are the top CPU consumers.

You can also use it in the case where CPU consumption spikes and then reduces: if that consistently happens with one program, then its *total* CPU will reflect that fact. Change the sort order to select the `TIME+` field.

Finally, if you don't want to keep a terminal window open, you can run `top` in "batch" mode and write the output to a file. Here's how to invoke it every second, and only capture the top 10 CPU consumers:

```
while true ; do top -b -n 1 | head -17 >> /tmp/top.log ; sleep 1 ; done
```

Comment: This seems to be helping. I'll use this. Thanks